# Quickest Way to open an excel file with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that has roughly 7600 rows and a lot of formulas in it. The spreadsheet can take a couple of minutes to load at times. Sometimes i just want to quickly check the date of an item in the spreadsheet but it just takes so long. I created a macro that reduces the load time to 32 seconds so far. Is there any way to make it load even faster than what I have coded so far?

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Workbooks.Open "foo_bar.xls", ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False
Windows("foo_bar.xls").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
MsgBox(ActiveCell.Value)
```

Comment: Don't forget `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` Then at the end of your sub `Application.ScreenUpdating=True`

Comment: is the item's date dependent on any formulas running beforehand?

Comment: Although screenupdating=false does make things faster, removing all the selects would be more important to make things faster. BTW, once a code has finished running, ScreenUpdating is automatically set to true

Comment: Create a new file, copying just the values - do not select everything, just cells with values (areas). You probably have some formatting in your empty cells.

Comment: How large is this file, and how often are you opening it?

Comment: @CharlesByrne your suggestion has cut down the load time for the spreadsheet by 10 seconds. Thank you.

Comment: @ Marcucciboy2, the dates are not dependent on any formulas running before hand.

Comment: @Pawel Czyz copy and pasting the values won't solve my issue because the sheet is updated by other people from time to time, and I want to check the date and item was added.

Comment: @Tim Williams the file is a 84mb spreadsheet. It will be checked daily to see if people added a new row of data to the sheet.

Comment: @ElectroMotiveHorse I'm glad it helped.  Don't forget to have OnError Goto [some label] statement with the label right before Application.ScreenUpdating=True in case there is a run time error.  Otherwise Excel UI will appear unresponsive if you have an error.

Comment: @Charles Byme will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of everyone I came to a solution. Use the following code to suppress alerts, prevent calculations, and supress the screen updates. Another key to making the spreadsheet open immediately was to fix all the links that were broken. Apparently, if the there are broken links, this will still cause a delay issue with loading the spreadsheet although it is told not to calculate or update any formulas referencing them.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open "foo_bar.xlsx",ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your other applications to the code, as well, change the file name

```
Sub GetIt()
    Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, LstRw As Long
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\foo_bar.xlsx")
    With wb
        Set sh = Sheets(1)
        With sh
            LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            MsgBox .Range("A" & LstRw).Value
        End With
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Save it with an xlsb extension.  Binary files tend to be around 4x smaller than non-binary files (on average), and they tend to open/close 4x faster too (on average).